# X,Y coordinates of a HTML table cell in javascript under iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, position, contextmenu

The code skeleton of my webpage is provided below and when I click on any td(pointed at the botton of the sample code),it calls javascript:onMouseDownOnTable()

```html
             html
                body
              div
     div
      div
       iframe
        html
         frameset
          frame
           html
            body
             div
              form
               div
                table
                 tbody
                  tr
                  td 
                  table
                   tbody
                    tr
                    td
                     table
                      tbody 
                       tr
                        td
                       div onmousedown ="javascript:onMouseDownOnTable(event)"                            
                                                                                              table
                                                                tbody                                       tr 
                                                                                                   td1 td2....tdN   <----- click on this td and open a context-menu at this position
                          
                                                                                                     
                                                                                                     
                                                                                                    tr 
                                                                                                        td1 td2..tdN
```

Can some one please provide me the way to get the correct X,Y coordinates of this the position of td in this case?

I am not able to get the correct position in IE and FF. In both there browsers position is coming at different places.
Using below method to get the coords but not getting correct position:

```js
 
     function  getContextMenuLocation(e, win)
      {  
            var curX = 0;
      var curY = 0;
      var scrollSumX = 0;
      var scrollSumY = 0;
      var oElement = e.target || e.srcElement;
      var oWindow = win || window;
 
      do
      {
       scrollSumX += oElement.scrollLeft;
       scrollSumY += oElement.scrollTop;
       curX += oElement.offsetLeft;
       curY += oElement.offsetTop;
       oElement = oElement.offsetParent;
       if (!oElement)
       {
        oElement = oWindow.frameElement;
        oWindow = oWindow.parent;
        curX -= oWindow.pageXOffset;
        curY -= oWindow.pageYOffset;
       }
      }
      while (oElement);
 
      curX += (e.offsetX == undefined ? e.layerX : e.offsetX) - scrollSumX;
      curY += (e.offsetY == undefined ? e.layerY : e.offsetY) - scrollSumY;
 
      return {x:curX, y:curY};
 
 
    };
```

Comment: Uh, please post your source code inline with the question. Not an external site. That IDE One site appears to render your code weird. Recommend that you do not use this site for future questions.

Comment: Is this some type of [Zen Coding](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/21/zen-coding-a-new-way-to-write-html-code/) ([Github:emmet](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet))?

Comment: I have no choice but to post the skeleton of the code because this can provide the exact structure of my web page.I know its little messy and not well formatted so kindly bear with me. I had pasted the method named as  "getContextMenuLocation" which i am using to get the x,y coords of the table cell.